# How to get rid of escape characters in PHP Mysql Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, character-encoding, escaping

I am trying to send a HTML code (variable `target`) through `AJAX` request by `escape(target)`, but before entering it into database i am encoding it again by following,

```
$post=target recieved on PHP page by POST
$post= htmlentities($_POST['posttext']);
$post = mysql_real_escape_string($post);
```

Now while reading it back from MySql, i am using `html_entity_decode($post)` to post the desired output.

PROBLEM:

On my local apache server everything is working fine but when i uploaded same code to online server, Few special characters of output are followed by `\`.

EG.

On my local server.

```
awk '/<ca>/{f=1;next}/<\/ca>/{f=0}f' $filename > ca.crt
awk '/<cert>/{f=1;next}/<\/cert>/{f=0}f' $filename > client.crt
awk '/<key>/{f=1;next}/<\/key>/{f=0}f' $filename > client.key
```

On online server.

```
awk \'/<ca>/{f=1;next}/<\\/ca>/{f=0}f\' $filename > ca.crt
awk \'/<cert>/{f=1;next}/<\\/cert>/{f=0}f\' $filename > client.crt
awk \'/<key>/{f=1;next}/<\\/key>/{f=0}f\' $filename > client.key
```

Am i missing something? Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

Don't encode html entities just for database insertion, especially if you're just going to decode them again each time anyways. waste of cpu cycles, and does NOTHING to protect against sql injection.

Your online server probably has [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled, which means it's either badly configured, or badly out-dated. magic_quotes will auto-escape quotes in any input to PHP, on the moronic assumption that no one could ever possibly want to send something to PHP and then **NOT** put it into the database.

Comment: Thanks, i never thought of magic quotes, was rumbling aroung encoding decoding. I added a function that solves my problem. Please accept it.